# Find a sinusoidal function $f(x)$ that satisfies each set of properties.

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

Graph two complete cycles of your function.

Answers are not unique.

a. Period of 6 hours with a minimum value of -2 at t=0 hr and a maximum value of 2 at t=3 hr.

b. Period of 24 hours with a maximum value of 20 at t=6 hr and a minimum value of 10 at t=18 hr.

I'm confused because what does this have to do with hours? Aren't the units supposed to be in radians? Also, do I just follow the $f(x)=A(\sin Bx+C)+D$ form?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very easy if you understand how the periodic functions operate:

A sine function is in range $[0 \; 2\pi]$ with period $2\pi$ but in the question we see the period is mentioned 6 hours. For a sine function with period of 6, it has to finish its period $2\pi$ in 6 hours. So the function is:

$\sin(2\pi t / 6)$

If you plot this function the domain (on the y axis) of sine function is $[-1 \; 1]$ but in the question we see -2 and 2 so we have to multiply the function by 2 to increase the domain to $[-2 \; 2]$:

$2\sin(2\pi t / 6)$

We can also simplify the sine function as follows:

$2\sin(\pi t / 3)$

now it is only the mater of finding the phase. We can see that in the question it has been mentioned that at time 0 the output is -2. In a standard $\sin(x)$ the value in $x=0$ should be 0 so we can determine that the phase is $\pi/2$. 
Therefore the final function would be

$2\sin(\pi t / 3 + \pi/2) $

I hope you can figure out the other question by yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I did! Thank you! :D